# C# null propagation

Tags: c#

Why this code throws `ArgumentNullException`:

```
string text = null;
        
var x = text?.Split('#');
        
var y = x.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

but this does not:

```
string text = null;
        
var z = text?.Split('#').ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

In the first snippet I have to use null propagation operator`?`:

```
string text = null;
        
var x = text?.Split('#');

var y = x?.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

but in the second it's not required to do:

```
var z = text?.Split('#')?.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

[https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCbIMj](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qOFpaO)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of how the expressions are evaluated:

```
string text = null; // text is null
        
var x = text?.Split('#'); // x is null
        
var y = x.ElementAtOrDefault(1); // null.ElementAtOrDefault throws an NRE
```

with your other example:

```
string text = null; // text is null
        
var z = text?.Split('#').ElementAtOrDefault(1); // z is null, nothing past ?. is evaluated because text was null
```

Fundamentally, the null propagation operator converts this:

```
Something?.SomethingElse(...)
```

To this ternary operation:

```
Something == null ? null : Something.SomethingElse(...)
```

And so the execution past the `?.` operator is short-circuited out (not executed) when the variable is `null`.

Comment: In addition, see how the compiler reduces the `?.` syntax sugar: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI4G5YQBmZMRAYUQG9ZF7lSQAWRAWQAoBKGuh/lPAD8iAC4BTAB6jEAXkTYArgBtlhGP34A3AIYAnRAC85YqaKGoAygAdlmURwDkAYkddUAUWXiAtuOyiAIKiAPJ6ACLiAGY6Kg4QXOr8AL589GmMyKwActy8Gpr0giIS0iZKqkmFiLoGkial5la29k6uiRna+ogAniaSnt5+AcFhkTFxHAn46QX0qTDJQA===

Comment: @gunr2171 yeah, it's not always compiled to a ternary statement, good call!

Comment: Actually, I'm semi-wrong. It's not a ternary because the compiler threw out the assignment as not needed. https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI4G5YQBmZMRAYUQG9ZF7lSQAWRAWQAoBKGuh/lPAD8iAC4BTAB6jEAXkTYArgBtlhGP34A3AIYAnRAC85YqaKGoAygAdlmURwDkAYkddUAUWXiAtuOyiAIKiAPJ6ACLiAGY6Kg4QXOqaDCgAnByGiXz0AL7ZiPkkyKwActy8GsnIEMKm0iZKqklVugaSJhLSFjZ2Di5uzcmtiACeJpKe3n4BwWGRMXEcCYOaaRwjWZW5sDlAA

Comment: @gunr2171 & Haney, thanks you ever so much ! You just open the door to a new world for me !

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation guys!